# What kind of plants are suitable to grow in Sydney's North Shore?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I would like to grow some vegetation and flowers in my apartment's small courtyard which is located in the north of Sydney. What kind of common plants could be easily grown for a family and don't have many pest issues?

The weather condition of Autumn and Winter in Sydney will be wet, sometimes showers and cloudy. However, my courtyard is faced to the north, which can have more sunshine.

Or are there any resources from which can find some relevant information for a new learner?

Comment: You say "vegetation" -- are you looking for plants that produce a lot of leaves, such as ivy? Or did you actually mean "vegetables"?